# Flutter Firebase Firestore Pinned Message Query

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have like this query

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> pageChat = _fireStore
        .collection('chat')
        .where('chatUsersId', arrayContains: firebaseUser!.uid)
        .where('chatStatus', isEqualTo: true)
        .orderBy('lastMessageDate', descending: true)
        .limit(10);
```

With what logic can I make a query for a pinned message? There is an array called chatUsersId, there are also fields that hold member ids called chater and pairer. I thought of solving it with 2 fields called chaterPinned:true and pairerPinned:true, but I couldn't figure out what logic I could use to query it.

The mentality I try is something like this

```
Query<Map<String, dynamic>> chatRef = _fireStore.collection("chat");
chatRef
    .where('chater', isEqualTo: firebaseUser!.uid)
    .where('chatStatus', isEqualTo: true)
    .orderBy('chaterPinned', descending: true);
chatRef
    .where('pairer', isEqualTo: firebaseUser!.uid)
    .where('chatStatus', isEqualTo: true)
    .orderBy('pairerPinned', descending: true);
chatRef
    .orderBy('lastMessageDate', descending: true)
    .limit(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good case for an [OR condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries) in your query.

Something like:

```
_fireStore
  .collection('chat')
  .where(
    Filter.or(
      Filter.and(
        Filter('chatUsersId', arrayContains: firebaseUser!.uid)
        Filter('chatStatus', isEqualTo: true)
      ),
      Filter('chaterPinned', isEqualTo: true),
      Filter('pairerPinned', isEqualTo: true)
    )
  )
  .orderBy('lastMessageDate', descending: true)
  .limit(10);
```

This returns all documents where the UID is in the `chatUsersId` array and that have `chatStatus` set to `true`, combined with all documents that either have `chaterPinned` [sic] or `pairerPinned` set to true.

Comment: Actually, I want to change this. It seems like this is a wrong query. I corrected the question. Is there a chance to do it that way? Then I will only see the messages I have pinned.

Comment: I tried the above, it doesn't work, pinned messages do not appear in the first messages.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is hard to help with. Is it clear what the query in my answer does? If so, does it match with your data model? If so and you still don't get the result you expect, can you show an example of a document (as a screenshot from the Firestore console) that you'd expect to be returned that is not showing up?

Comment: If lastmessageDate is less than 10 messages, it will not appear in the first 10 messages. As a result, it gives the same result as my normal query.

Comment: Ah, in that case you'll want to order on `isPinned` first and only then on `lastMessageDate`. I'm not certain that is supported though, so give it a try. --- If not supported, the only way I can think of is to do two queries (each with `limit(10)`). That will likely result in too many results though, so I hope the single query can handle the case.